# How to read a target bar

Tags: xcom-2

How do you read the color bar when making a shot?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's called the *"shot breakdown bar,"* and has been disabled in the base-game.  You need a mod or .ini tweak to enable it.  The two I could find that add it are [Perfect Information](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=625737801) and [Tactical HUD Tweaks](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=640402081)

From the latter link:

> Red = Hit, but not Crit
>   Yellow = Crit
>   Green = Graze
>   Gray = Miss

Comment: Yes, I've got Perfect Information mod but I didn't realize the base game hadn't it. Can you please elaborate on the colors? Am I correct that the whole bar represents a target's health and read/yellow show a number of points if you hit/crit the target? But green/gray show a probability to graze/miss (taken the whole bar is 100%)?

Comment: @UserControl: No it has nothing to do with health.  The whole bar represents 100% probability.  The individual colors represent the breakdown of your chances for the shot to hit/miss/crit/graze.  It's the information you already have from the percentages, but presented visually.

Answer (score 1):

You still have all the numbers all around the bar. From the numbers given, I deduce that red is "normal hit", yellow is "critical", green is "dodge", and gray is "miss". Snipe away!